# Using numpy and scipy from Anaconda in xcode on a mac

Tags: xcode, macos, numpy, scipy, anaconda

I want to use the numpy and scipy Python libraries in combination with Xcode on my Mac, but do not get it up and running.

I use:

- macOS High Sierra
- Xcode 9.2
- a local programming environment for Python 3.6

And I am able to run pure (no additional libraries) Python code in that environment without any problems. Now I also want to use numpy/scipy functionality and therefore installed Anaconda 3 on my machine. But when I try to run the following simple code in Xcode:

```
 import numpy as np
 a = np.arange(1, 10)
 print(a)
```

I get the following error message:

> File "/Users/oliverewald/Python/Python/Work.py", line 1, in 
>       import numpy as np
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
>   Program ended with exit code: 1

Somehow the libraries that came with the Anaconda installation are not known/available in my local Python environment.

What am I missing? How can I get it running?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?   I'm having the same problem.  I followed the recommended installation procedure using the Terminal command:  "brew install numpy scipy ipython jupyter".  This installation completed, but I cannot access scipy or numpy from Xcode.  Probably a path problem but I haven't been able to fix it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Modules installed in the Anaconda environment work only within the environment. I no longer have a working Mac to check this with, but I think you can enter the Anaconda environment from within Xcode.

The other option (without using Anaconda) is to use Python's `pip` to install the modules in the Python 3.6 environment.